# Using preg_replace in php for whitespace between <br/> and <p> tags

Tags: php, whitespace

I need to remove this string if found in my string:

```
<p><br/>   </p>
```

Cant replace this:

```
<p><br/>Test.   </p>
```

The whitespace expression I am using wasn't working for that, thank you for your help!

Comment: And what whitespace expression would that be? Can you post what you have so we can tell you how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
preg_replace('!<br/>\s+</p>!', '<br/></p>', $variable_name);
```

Comment: Oh: I used exclamation points so that I didn't need to escape the slashes. That will remove any whitespace and only whitespace, directly between a <br/> and a </p>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('%<p><br/>\s*</p>%', '', $string);
```

But what do you mean with *Cant replace this* ? Should this line also be replaced or not or how?

**Update:**
To clarify: Do you want to have **only** whitespaces removed or the whole `<p><br/>   </p>` ?

Comment: str_replace won't work with regex. replace it with `preg_replace`. Even then the tags are removed, too.

Comment: I read the question as too remove the whitespace between the tags, but yes it can be read in both ways.

Comment: thank you very much, this is working..

preg_replace('!<p><br/>\s+</p>!', '', $content);

Completely removes the tags.